# Creating new variables by subsetting data

Tags: r

I want to make new variables that contain information around each individual event for a week: 3 days up to an event and 3 days after. 
What I have:

```
df <- Date   APP  DE10 
  2014-09-22 0    1.010 
  2014-09-19 0    1.043
  2014-09-18 0    1.081
  2014-09-17 0    1.050
  2014-09-16 0    1.061
  2014-09-15 0    1.067
  2014-09-12 1    1.082
  2014-09-11 0    1.041
  2014-09-10 0    1.047
  2014-09-09 0    0.996
  2014-09-08 0    0.953
  2014-09-05 0    0.928
  2014-09-04 1    0.970
  2014-09-03 0    0.955
  2014-09-02 0    0.931
  2014-09-01 0    0.882
```

What I want my dataset to look like:

```
 APP      Indicator  DE10_Event1 DE10_Event2
 0        1          1.050      0.996
 0        2          1.061      0.996
 0        3          1.067      0.996
 1        4          1.082      0.970
 0        5          1.041      0.955
 0        6          1.047      0.931
 0        7          0.996      0.882
```

I have been trying different things, but it has not worked out.

***Edit***

The dataset I want looks as the one above. I need it in order to plot multiple lines in a figure to compare market effects three days prior and after an event. In short, I want a figure like the one below but with more lines, each representing a development up until and after an event. `APP=1` indicates when an event takes place, so I need `Indicator=4` when `APP=1`.

I hope this revision makes sense. Otherwise feel free to ask me again. I really appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: It does not look like the output you write here can come from the input... there are only Monday through Friday data in the top data frame, and there are all day of week in the bottom data frame. Also, where do `DE10_Event1` and `DE10_Event2` come from? Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, so the idea I had was that based on the APP dummy the Weekday variable can be made in each case, and then maybe it would be possible to create DE10_Event1 and DE10_Event2 conditional on APP=1, so their values are taken as APP[+3], APP[+2], APP[+1], APP[0], APP[-1], APP[-2], APP[-3]. I hope this clarified my question a bit. :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us an example of an input data frame that you would like to process + the output data frame that would be the correct answer? It's pretty straightforward to get a day of week just from the `Date` field, but I still don't understand how to use the `DE10` field to split it up into two events. Thanks again.

Comment: I also don't understand the question at all

Comment: mysteRious, I revised the question. I realise the name I gave the once "Weekday", now "Indicator",-variable was misleading. It is meant as a support for the figure I want to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still not clear, but if I understood correctly, what you need is not to create a new variable, but to select the days around each APP occurrence. I'm posting a new answer, since that is a different question.

Reading your example data:

```
df <- read.table( text = c('
  Date   APP  DE10 
  2014-09-22 0    1.010 
  2014-09-19 0    1.043
  2014-09-18 0    1.081
  2014-09-17 0    1.050
  2014-09-16 0    1.061
  2014-09-15 0    1.067
  2014-09-12 1    1.082
  2014-09-11 0    1.041
  2014-09-10 0    1.047
  2014-09-09 0    0.996
  2014-09-08 0    0.953
  2014-09-05 0    0.928
  2014-09-04 1    0.970
  2014-09-03 0    0.955
  2014-09-02 0    0.931
  2014-09-01 0    0.882' ),
  header = TRUE )
```

Now identify where you have APPs and get the data around it. There's certainly more elegant ways to do this, but this would do. It will create a new data.frame with all you need for your plots:

```
# Itentify the rows where APP is 1:
APProws <- as.numeric(rownames( df[ df[,'APP'] == 1, ] ))

# An empty data.frame to receive the data:
APP.df <- data.frame(
  Event = rep(NA, length(APProws)*7),
  Date = as.Date('2000-12-31'),
  DE10 = NA,
  Indicator = NA )

n <- 0
for( i in APProws ) {

  rows <- (n*7+1):(n*7+7)

  APP.df$Event[rows] <- paste('Event', n+1)
  APP.df$Date[rows] <- df$Date[(i-3):(i+3)]
  APP.df$DE10[rows] <- df$DE10[(i-3):(i+3)]
  APP.df$Indicator[n*7+4] <- '1'

  n <- n+1
}; rm(i, n, rows)
```

Now you have everithing you need for your plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(APP.df, aes(Date, DE10)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(
    data = subset(APP.df, Indicator == 1),
    aes(xintercept = as.numeric(Date)),
    color = 'red' ) +
  facet_grid( ~Event, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

If this is what you need, I really recommend that you edit the title of your post, since it's misleading. Describe what you trying to accomplish, not the way you think it's the way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your example data:

```
df <- read.table( text = c('
  Date   APP  DE10 
  2014-09-22 0    1.010 
  2014-09-19 0    1.043
  2014-09-18 0    1.081
  2014-09-17 0    1.050
  2014-09-16 0    1.061
  2014-09-15 0    1.067
  2014-09-12 1    1.082
  2014-09-11 0    1.041
  2014-09-10 0    1.047
  2014-09-09 0    0.996
  2014-09-08 0    0.953
  2014-09-05 0    0.928
  2014-09-04 1    0.970
  2014-09-03 0    0.955
  2014-09-02 0    0.931
  2014-09-01 0    0.882' ),
  header = TRUE )
```

Add week day number:

```
df$Weekday <- strftime(df$Date, '%u')
```

Now count the number of events per APP and week day, then spread your data. You can try using dplyr/tidyr. I'm accustomed to data.table, so:

```
library(data.table)

df <- as.data.table(df)

df[ , Event := paste0('DE10_Event', 1:.N) , by = .(APP, Weekday) ]

df.s <- dcast(df, APP + Weekday ~ Event, value.var = 'DE10')

> df.s
   APP Weekday DE10_Event1 DE10_Event2 DE10_Event3 DE10_Event4
1:   0       1       1.010       1.067       0.953       0.882
2:   0       2       1.061       0.996       0.931          NA
3:   0       3       1.050       1.047       0.955          NA
4:   0       4       1.081       1.041          NA          NA
5:   0       5       1.043       0.928          NA          NA
6:   1       4       0.970          NA          NA          NA
7:   1       5       1.082          NA          NA          NA
```

Comment: Yep! [rfairy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6729815/rfairy), your trouble was in figuring out the individual steps to reach your solution (which is the most common hindrance in anything). You can easily find alternative ways if you search SO for the individual steps.

Comment: Carlos, thanks for your answer! However, I was not clear in what I was exactly looking for. The "Weekday"-variable is more of an "Indicator"-variable, indicating the number of days around an event. Thus, `Indicator=4` is on an event date.

Comment: Now that is a different question, and still not clear what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your contributions!

For others who are looking for a solution to a similar problem, I combined the answers I got into:

```
df$APProws <- 1:nrow(df) #Variable with row numbers
events_rows <- df %>% filter(APP==1) %>% select(APProws) #Indicator for row number for event, APP=1
```

Subtract the two variables to get row distance from event:

```
diffs <- data.frame(df %>% 
    mutate(Event1_DE10=df$APProws-events_rows$APProws[1]) %>% 
    mutate(Event2_DE10=df$APProws-events_rows$APProws[2]))
```

Plot the figure:

```
diffs %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Event1_DE10,y=DE10), color="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Event2_DE10,y=DE10), color="red") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")  +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-3,3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.3,0.7))
```

Here is the result:

[image: Bond yield development]

Comment: Good! Thanks for posting your own solution, that's aways helpful.