# Subsetting dataset into new variables based on event dates

Tags: r

I am looking into German bond yield development around certain event dates indicated by `APP=1` in the dataset below. For example, on both 4 Sep 2014 and 12 Sep 2014 an event occurs.

I want to compare how the market reacts three days prior and after the event. In short, I want my figure below to contain one more line, representing the time around the second event.

[image]

In order to make such a figure I need to manipulate my data. Here is my current dataset:

```
df <- Date   APP  DE10 
  2014-09-22 0    1.010 
  2014-09-19 0    1.043
  2014-09-18 0    1.081
  2014-09-17 0    1.050
  2014-09-16 0    1.061
  2014-09-15 0    1.067
  2014-09-12 1    1.082
  2014-09-11 0    1.041
  2014-09-10 0    1.047
  2014-09-09 0    0.996
  2014-09-08 0    0.953
  2014-09-05 0    0.928
  2014-09-04 1    0.970
  2014-09-03 0    0.955
  2014-09-02 0    0.931
  2014-09-01 0    0.882
```

I want my dataset to look like this:

```
 APP      Indicator  DE10_Event1 DE10_Event2
 0        1          1.050      0.996
 0        2          1.061      0.996
 0        3          1.067      0.996
 1        4          1.082      0.970
 0        5          1.041      0.955
 0        6          1.047      0.931
 0        7          0.996      0.882
```

This way, I will have the option of plotting the lines in the same figure, as they now have the same y-axis and x-axis.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Isn't this similar to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002631/creating-new-variables-by-subsetting-data)

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem as before, but I did not make my question clear enough I think. I hope I have now.

Comment: I did edit it as you can see. But not in a satisfying it seemed from the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this is much easier to understand than the original. If you only have a few events, this will work to produce the kind of chart you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

I read in your data as a data frame `dd`. First converted `Date` to a `Date` type and then identified the event dates:

```
> dd$Date <- as.Date(dd$Date)
> events <- dd %>% filter(APP==1) %>% select(Date)
> events$Date
[1] "2014-09-12" "2014-09-04"
```

Next use those dates to create one new column of date differences for each event:

```
diffs <- dd %>% 
    mutate(Event1_DE10=-interval(ymd(dd$Date),ymd(events$Date[1])) %/% days(1)) %>% 
    mutate(Event2_DE10=-interval(ymd(dd$Date),ymd(events$Date[2])) %/% days(1))
```

This will give you:

```
> diffs
# A tibble: 16 x 5
   Date         APP  DE10 Event1_DE10 Event2_DE10
   <date>     <int> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2014-09-22     0 1.01          10.         18.
 2 2014-09-19     0 1.04           7.         15.
 3 2014-09-18     0 1.08           6.         14.
 4 2014-09-17     0 1.05           5.         13.
 5 2014-09-16     0 1.06           4.         12.
 6 2014-09-15     0 1.07           3.         11.
 7 2014-09-12     1 1.08           0.          8.
 8 2014-09-11     0 1.04          -1.          7.
 9 2014-09-10     0 1.05          -2.          6.
10 2014-09-09     0 0.996         -3.          5.
11 2014-09-08     0 0.953         -4.          4.
12 2014-09-05     0 0.928         -7.          1.
13 2014-09-04     1 0.970         -8.          0.
14 2014-09-03     0 0.955         -9.         -1.
15 2014-09-02     0 0.931        -10.         -2.
16 2014-09-01     0 0.882        -11.         -3.
```

You can overplot lines, one for each event, and then the vertical line at the end:

```
diffs %>% ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=Event1_DE10,y=DE10), color="blue") +
    geom_line(aes(x=Event2_DE10,y=DE10), color="red") + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If you only want -3 to +3 on the x-axis, just add a plus sign to the end of the code above and `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-3,3))` to chop the plot at those x-limits.

If you have more than a handful of dates, you may need to adjust the `mutate` part so that it gives a new column for all event dates in `events$Date`.

To zoom in the plot but not chop off the data outside the axis boundaries, use `coord_cartesian`:

```
diffs %>% ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=Event1_DE10,y=DE10), color="blue") +
    geom_line(aes(x=Event2_DE10,y=DE10), color="red") + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed") +
    labs(x="Days from Event") + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-3,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution, mysteRious! However, I want to ask you how I might change days(1) in mutate, as you can see the events often take place before a weekend, so for example Event1_DE10 is missing -1, -2 and Event2_DE10 -2, -3, which makes my figure flawed when I add `limits=c(-3,3)`. Maybe refer to the number of the previous observation as a count instead?

Comment: `days(1)` is not related to this issue... it just counts intervals of 1 day. Do you mean you want the plot to include all the data from outside of (-3,3) so that it doesn't look like the line starts at x=-1 for the red trace?

Comment: Yes I guess the issue is related to the interval as it is based on the dates. If you try inputting the code you provided and adding `x_scale_continuous(limits=c(-3,3))` to the ggplot, you will see that the figure only plots until -1. This happens because the two event variables do not show `Event1_DE10 = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)` `Event2_DE10 = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)` around the event but `Event1_DE10 = c(-5, -4, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3)` and `Event2_DE10 = c(-5, -4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)` instead.

Comment: Changed the `mutate` so 09-03 shows up as -1 from 09-04, and so on; added a solution for the zoom issue with `coord_cartesian`.